# Problema con DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un problema con un DataAnnotation personalizada.

```
public class RequiredInt32 : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(value) == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("MENSAJE_PERSONALIZADO");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Tengo ese código. Resulta que si entra en el `if`, no me devuelve `MENSAJE_PERSONALIZADO` me devuelve `El campo no es válido`. Para que me devuelva el mensaje que quiero, necesito ponerlo explicitamente.

```
[RequiredInt32(ErrorMessage = @"MENSAJE_PERSONALIZADO")]
```

Que es lo que tengo mal y como puedo hacer para que tenga un mensaje por defecto. Gracias!

Comment: Creo que ya respondieron tu pregunta en este [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17474942/945092)

Comment: @NicolásLoaiza perfecto! Era loque buscaba. Muchas gracias!